# TMS TPlannerMonthView: get selected item text

Tags: delphi, tms

I'm new to Delphi and I'm trying to get the name from the item that I have selected in the Planner. The text for the item is set after using `PlannerMonthView1.CreateItem` like this:

```
  DbDate := FrmMain.FDTable1.FindField('NOT_DATE').AsFloat;
  FrmMain.FDTable1.First;
  for i := 0 to FrmMain.ListBox1.Count-1 do
  begin
    With PlannerMonthView1.CreateItem do
    begin
      DbDate := FrmMain.FDTable1.FindField('NOT_DATE').AsFloat;
      ItemStartTime := DbDate;
      ItemEndTime := DbDate;
      Text.Text := FrmMain.FDTable1.FindField('NOT_NAME').AsString;
      FrmMain.FDTable1.Next;
    end;
```

My problem is that there is no component list from TMS for the Planner tool. I have tried it like this:

```
ShowMessage(FKalender.PlannerMonthView1.CreateItem.Text.GetText[2]);
```

...but that shows an empty message box.

Comment: property Selected: TPlannerItem; Returns the currently selected item. All in the manual : http://www.tmssoftware.biz/Download/Manuals/TMS%20TPLANNER.pdf look for "Item selection in the planner"

Comment: Hi, thats for your help. But now i have a other problem. i have try it like :
`Text := PlannerMonthView1.Items.Select;`
but that is not wirking becaus of "Not enought true Parameter"

Answer (score 1):

The (constructor) method name `.CreateItem()` is not for fun: it really creates a new item. Why not assigning that to a variable?

```
var
  myPlannerItem: TPlannerItem;
begin
  myPlannerItem:= PlannerMonthView1.CreateItem();
  ...
  // Accessing the item's text (all lines at once)
  ShowMessage( myPlannerItem.Text.Text );
  ...
  // Unrelated to the one we've added: show the currently selected item's
  // 3rd line of its text
  ShowMessage( PlannerMonthView1.Selected.Text[2] );
  ...
  // The documentation http://www.tmssoftware.biz/download/manuals/TMS TPLANNER.pdf
  // around page 96 instructs you to use the Planner to delete the item instead
  // of freeing the object itself
  PlannerMonthView1.FreeItem( myPlannerItem );
```

Note that this is not a "name", but instead a variable. Usage of `with` should reduced to a minimum and it only makes sense on newly created objects if you don't need to access them later.

> ShowMessage(FKalender.PlannerMonthView1.CreateItem.Text.GetText[2]);

This doesn't show any text because you just created another new item thru `.CreateItem()` instead of accessing any previously created one, so all its properties have their default values (with `.Text` being empty).

Comment: Okay, i got that. But there is no .Text for the PlannerMonthView1.Text sorry maybe im a little bit lost but i i have tried it with the Selected Methode but that also does not work for me. Text := PlannerMonthView1.Items.Select(Item); gives me the error  "incompatible typ 'String' and 'procedure'"

Comment: Selecting an item and wanting to know what is currently selected are two different things: the procedure `Select()` cannot be assigned to your variable `Text` of the type `String`. I've edited my answer to include more examples. Also please take the [tour].